# Referencing a dynamically created control in a new TabPage

Tags: c#, winforms

newbie programmer here after hours of searching has left me stumped.

I'm having trouble with referencing a control inside a tab created at RunTime with a button press. Basically what I have is a tabletop RPG calculator, using a Windows Form, that has a tabControl holding tab pages, with each tab page holding user-inputted stats for that individual enemy to be used in calculations.

The problem is that I want the user to be able to click a button to generate a new enemy tab page. Here is my code for generating an enemy tab page with a TextBox.

```
    int enemyNumber = 0;

    // Creates a new Enemy Tab
    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Create a new TabPage
        var newTabPage = new TabPage()
        {
            Text = "Enemy " + enemyNumber,
        };

        // Add Enemy Name Box
        var newEnemyNameBox = new TextBox()
        {
            Name = "enemyNameBox" + enemyNumber,
            Text = "",
            Location = new Point(127, 11),
            Size = new Size(133, 20)
        };

        // Add the controls to the new Enemy tab
        newTabPage.Controls.Add(newEnemyNameBox);

         // Add the TabPage to the TabControl
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTabPage);

        // Increases the enemy's "reference number" by 1
        // So that enemy tabs will be generated in order enemyTab0, enemyTab1, etc.
        enemyNumber += 1;
    }
```

This all works nicely. Unfortunately, after this point things have gotten ugly. I need to reference that TextBox named "enemyNameBox" + enemyNumber, and I'm not sure how to do so.

What I did was create "archVariables" to store the values from whatever enemy tab is selected, then use the appropriate archVariable in the program's calculations. IE: archEnemyName. The idea is that whatever tab the user is currently selected on (determined via SelectedIndex) the TextBox from that page will be used for the program's output.

Here are the two things I've tried after researching the matter:

```
    // Attempt 1
    private void defendCalcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.SelectedIndex; i++)
       {
           archEnemyNameBox = ((TextBox)Controls["enemyNameBox" + i]).Text;
       }
    }
```

This code simply throws a NullReferenceException when I press the button. So after researching more I tried this:

```
    // Attempt 2
    private void defendCalcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.SelectedIndex; i++)
       {
           TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
           tb2 = ((TextBox)(enemyTab.Controls.Find("enemyNameBox" + i, true)));
           archEnemyNameBox = tb2.Text;
       }
    }
```

This time I got an Error: Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

I feel like the second method I have here is probably closer to the correct way to do this, but apparently I'm still not getting it right. I've learned a lot by searching the information on stackoverflow and msdn.microsoft but nothing has gotten me past this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically the problem with your second attemp is that `enemyTab.Controls.Find("enemyNameBox" + i, true)` returns an array of Controls `Control[]` and you're trying to convert that to a Control here is the problem, you should get the first control in that array and then convert it to a Control so it should be like this:

```
private void defendCalcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.SelectedIndex; i++)
   {
       TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
       tb2 = ((TextBox)(enemyTab.Controls.Find("enemyNameBox" + i, true)[0]));
       archEnemyNameBox = tb2.Text;
   }
}
```

but it is not the BestWay to do so it seems that everytime a user adds a new tabPage it will have the same Controls right? so why not create an userControl with any Control you have on your TabPage? so when you press the user press to add a new tab your code should be like so:

```
private void CreateNewEnemyTab()
{
    var newTabPage = new TabPage()
    {
        Text = "Enemy " + enemyNumber,
    };
    EnemyTabUserControl enemyTab = new EnemyTabUserControl(enemyNumber);
    here the EnemyTabUserControl should have all the components you need;
    newTabPage.Controls.Add(enemyTab);
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTabPage);
}
```

and the code to bring the TextBox from the current tab could be as follow (you are going to need to reference LINQ)

```
using System.Linq;


//First Lets create this property, it should return the selected EnemyTabUserControl inside the tabControl
public EnemyTabUserControl CurrentTab {
    get { 
         return tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<EnemyTabUserControl>().First();
    }
}


// then if we make the textbox you want to reference from outside the code we can do this
CurrentTab.NameOfTheTextBox;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! The solution you suggested is indeed much easier to handle and it works like a charm, exactly what I needed. And perhaps more importantly I learned something new from this. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Patrick has solved your fundamental problem, but I don't think you need the loop in there at all.  Here I've broken the steps out so you can see what needs to happen a little better:

```
    private void defendCalcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        Control[] matches = this.Controls.Find("enemyNameBox" + tabControl1.SelectedIndex.ToString(), true);
        if (matches.Length > 0 && matches[0] is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)matches[0];
            archEnemyNameBox = tb.Text;
        }
    }
```